# Фейл ajax запроса в контроллере

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Как сделать `fail` ajax запроса в контроллере,чтобы после обработать его по параметру `OnFailure`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верните любой запрос со статус кодом ошибки, например 404

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Smth(string name)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "Can't find");
}
```